# JDBC integrated security with jar

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, executable-jar, integrated-security

I found a lot of thing about SQL Server integrated security with JDBC 3.0 but i cannot solve my problem so here is my problem:

I have an application with a JDBC connection using integratedSecurity. I put the sqljdbc_auth.dll file in system32 folder, and tried many other locations (java home, application lib folder...). When the application is running under Netbeans, the integrated security work perfectly. But if i run the application executing the jar, I have this message:

"This driver is not configured for integrated security".

I tried many solutions found through the web, but it did not solve the problem.

I noticed that the connection work when I run the application from console too

```
java -jar my/app/path
```

I really don't know what can be the solution.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx "Connecting with Integrated Authentication on Windows"

Comment: What do you mean by "if i run the application executing the jar"? Isn't it the same thing as executing `java -jar my/app/path`?

Comment: I don't think the problem is my connection url because the jdbc connection work when the application is executed in Netbeans or in console. here is my connection url : `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MY_DATABASE;integratedSecurity=true;`

Comment: @JB Nizet: I meant that when I'm double clicking on the jar to execute it, the error message pop up and the connection fail. But when i'm launching it in the console, it works.